# Merge multiple binary encoded rows into one in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
  A B C D E F
0 0 1 0  0  0
1 1 0 0  0  0 
2 0 1 0  0  0
3 0 0 0  1  0
4 0 0 1  0  0
```

There are several rows that share a `1` in their columns and in each row there is only one `1` present. I want to merge the rows with each other so the resulting `dataFrame` would onyl consist of one row, that combines all the `1`s of the dataframe, like this:

```
  A B C D E F
0 1 1 1  1  0
```

Is there a smart, easy way to do this with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), then compare for greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and last convert to `0,1` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
s = df.sum().ge(1).view('i1')
```

Another idea if `0,1` values only is use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with convert mask to `0,1`:

```
s = df.any().view('i1')
print (s)
A    1
B    1
C    1
D    1
E    1
F    0
dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
df.sum().ge(1).astype(int)
Out[316]: 
A    1
B    1
C    1
D    1
E    1
F    0
dtype: int32
```